# Heat handling in BIPV System

Tags: solar-energy, photovoltaics

In a BIPV System, how is the heat handled? I mean the cells absorb the solar radiation and along with that the heat. So how is this heat handled? I was reading that the conventional solar system is placed at a distance from the floor of the roof allowing for ventilation which provides a good way for keeping the system from overheating but since let's say in a building the glass used is acting as a solar cell then how is the glass kept from overheating?

Answer (score 0):

I installed my panels with a 20cm (8") air gap behind with vents top and bottom.

Get full output on summer days so works well.

Also put them at 70 degrees so winter energy collection is improved.

If these panels get overheated then expect losses up to 50%